# isPersistent parameter ignored in PasswordSignInAsync

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-identity

I am using ASP.NET Core Identity to implement the login functionality. I have the following code for handling the login.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, 
                       model.RememberMe, false);

        if(result.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid Login Attempt");
    }

    return View(model);
 }
```

When using the Chrome browser, even if the `model.RememberMe` is false, `SignInManager` is creating a persistent cookie (if I close the browser and open it again, the cookie is still there).

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhVJE.png)

However, if I use the Microsoft Edge browser, everything works correctly. So, what should I do to make this work with the Chrome browser?

Comment: Hi @chazer gayan, are you sure you close the whole google browser instead of just one tab of the browser? It could clear the cookie if I set IsPersistent false.